# UI side of Shiny not showing up when Running App

Tags: r, shiny

So I've learned from my teammates that the server side of a RShiny app doesn't need to be completed for the UI side of an app to be shown.

Here's a bit of my code:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(title = "Enrolment Analytics"),
dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(

#can change tab names and icons here.
menuItem("Summary Tables", tabName = "Summary Tables", icon = icon("table")),
menuItem("Visualizations", tabName = "Visualizations", icon = icon("line-chart"))  

)
),

dashboardBody(
tabItems(
tabItem(tabName = "Summary Tables", 
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Teaching Load ", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
              selectInput("courseCode1", "Course code: ", 
                          choices = as.list(unique(data1$discipline))), 
              numericInput("Month", "1 = January, 2 = February, ..., 12 = December", value = 6), 
              numericInput("Year", "2007, 2008, ..., 2017", value = 2007)
              ), 
          box(title = "Summary ", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
              plotOutput("tl1"))
        ))
), 

tabItem(tabName = "Visualizations", 
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Teaching Load", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
              selectInput("courseCodeOne", "First discipline: ", 
                          choices = as.list(unique(data1$discipline))), 
              selectInput("courseCodeTwo", "Second discipline: ", 
                          choices = as.list(unique(data1$discipline))), 
              selectInput("courseCodeThree", "Third discipline: ", 
                          choices = as.list(unique(data1$discipline)))
              ), 
          box(title = "Teaching Load Graph", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
              plotOutput("tl2"))
        ))
)
)
```

When I run the app, the sidebar shows Visualizations and Summary Tables but on the server side of things, only the visualizations boxes show up and the summary tables do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues with your code:

1.) `tabName` must not contain spaces (which is not clear from the help pages).

2.) You had a bracket error (Second `tabItem` was not included in the brackets of `tabItem`.

If you correct those two mistakes, the UI is working fine:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Enrolment Analytics"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(

    #can change tab names and icons here.
    menuItem("Summary Tables", tabName = "SummaryTables", icon = icon("table")),
    menuItem("Visualizations", tabName = "Visualizations", icon = icon("line-chart"))  

  )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "SummaryTables", 
              fluidRow(
                box(title = "Teaching Load ", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                    selectInput("courseCode1", "Course code: ", 
                                choices = 1:5), 
                    numericInput("Month", "1 = January, 2 = February, ..., 12 = December", value = 6), 
                    numericInput("Year", "2007, 2008, ..., 2017", value = 2007)
                ), 
                box(title = "Summary ", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                    plotOutput("tl1"))
              )), 
    ## BRACKET ERROR WAS HERE

    tabItem(tabName = "Visualizations", 
            fluidRow(
              box(title = "Teaching Load", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                  selectInput("courseCodeOne", "First discipline: ", 
                              choices = 1:10), 
                  selectInput("courseCodeTwo", "Second discipline: ", 
                              choices = 1:10), 
                  selectInput("courseCodeThree", "Third discipline: ", 
                              choices = 1:10)
              ), 
              box(title = "Teaching Load Graph", status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE, 
                  plotOutput("tl2"))
            ) 
    )
  ))
)
server = function(input, output, session){

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]